# How do binomial double trees work in h2o?

Tags: python, r, h2o

How does `h2o` create trees when we set `binomial_double_trees` to `TRUE`?! If I can find the optimal number of trees using `h2o.grid`, then why do we need `binomial_double_trees = TRUE`(also one question more, what is the difference between internal trees and simple trees )
[Reference](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/binomial_double_trees.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet from the documentation:

- http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/binomial_double_trees.html

  When building classification models, this option specifies to build twice as many internal trees as the number of trees (one per class). Enabling this option can lead to higher accuracy but lower speed times, while disabling this can result in faster model building. This option is disabled by default.

When building a classification tree model, what happens under the hood is when the user asks for 10 trees, for example, the algorithm builds 10 trees *for each class* of the response column.  This is why tree algorithms are computationally expensive for heavily multinomial problems.  The number of trees that actually get calculated is numTrees * numClasses.

The binomial classification case is special where the 0 and 1 classes can be treated as mirror images of each other.  So only the 0 case is calculated and then the 1 case is just "1 - p".

The `binomial_double_trees` flag tells the algorithm to not use the mirror image shortcut, and to instead actually fully calculate out a second set of trees for the 1 class.  In practice, this will increase the training time, scoring time, and model size.

(Also note that the `binomial_double_trees` flag is unrelated to grid search, or finding the optimal number of trees.)

Comment: I am using sparkML's RandomForestClassifier. From the docs description, would I then just need to set `numTrees = whatever_id_normally_set * 2` to have the same situation (or perhaps I am misunderstanding what "internal" trees are)?